# Is there a way to send multiple image to tf serving model?

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying this below code but I got unexpected error

This is my code for getting input and pass it to model.

```
def get_instances(dir = '/test_data'):

        instances = list()
        file_names = [file.split('/')[-1] for file in os.listdir(dir)]
        for file in file_names :
          image = nv.imread(os.path.join(dir ,file), resize = (300,300), color_mode='rgb',normalize=True)
          image = combine_rgb_xyz(image)
          #image = nv.expand_dims(image,axis=0)
          instances.append(image)
        return np.array(instances) ,file_names
```

After I send these data to model with below code :

```
def make_prediction(instances):
   url = get_url()
   data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": instances.tolist()})
   headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
   json_response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
   predictions = json.loads(json_response.text)['predictons']
   return predictions
```

but I get unexpected output :

```
'predictons'
```

Comment: Is that the full output? It looks like you are expecting a `predictons` key in the response object. But this is a misspelling of "predictions", and if the response is coming from TF Serving, I would not expect TF Serving to have misspelled "predictions".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.make_tensor_proto` and `tf.make_ndarray` for image numpy array to/from tensor conversions. Then, you can use 'serving_default' signature to make predictions and pass multiple images to serving_default request to achieve faster results. 'serving_default' signature supports multiple images to be processed at once since it has 4d input (batch, height, width, channel).
Please refer this [guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/serving-an-image-classification-model-with-tensorflow-serving-c4657584d73d) to pass multiple images to TF serving.